# python remove an value from list of dictionaries json file including comma (,)

Tags: python, json

I have a josn file

```
 [ 
    {
      "x":"y",
      "a":"b",
      "p":{
        "l":[
          "m",
          "n"
        ],
        "q":[
          "g",
          "h"
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

I would like to remove the value "h" and the comma (,) preceeding it using python.

I tried the following .

```
import json
data=json.load(open("data.json"))

for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i]["p"]["q"][1] == "h":
            data.pop(i)
            break
```

Can anyone help me in doing this.

Comment: The example you provided is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you want the *comma*?

Comment: If you remove the item, the comma will go automatically.

Comment: Can you please help me how to remove the item

Comment: @jonrsharpe I donot want the comma, I want it to be removed

Comment: As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said, once you remove the "h", and dump the Python `dict` to a JSON string or file, the comma will be gone. The `json` `dump` function knows how to produce valid JSON!

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you please help me how to remove "h"

Comment: @PM2Ring I have changed the Json data. Can you please have a look now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152457/discussion-between-venkatsai-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get rid of the "h" item by using the `list.remove` method.

```
import json

data = [ 
    {
      "x":"y",
      "a":"b",
      "p":{
        "l":[
          "m",
          "n"
        ],
        "q":[
          "g",
          "h"
        ]
      }
    }
]

data[0]['p']['q'].remove("h")
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        "x": "y",
        "a": "b",
        "p": {
            "l": [
                "m",
                "n"
            ],
            "q": [
                "g"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. list.remove(x) worked. I manupulated some part of your code and it worked for my data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `del` instead of pop. The comma will removed because they are only inserted to separate data elements.

I'm assuming your data look like:

```
data = [
        {'x': 'y', 'a': 'b', 'p': {'l': ['m', 'n'], 'q': ['g']}}, 
        {'another': 'dict'}
       ]

for d in data:
    if "p" in d and "q" in p["d"]:
            if p["d"]["q"][1] == "h":
                del d["p"]["q"][1]
                break
```

Comment: Tom Sitter I tried this too. However, it gives me a KeyError:0

Comment: KeyError is likely because not every dict in your list has a `p` and `q` key. You can do nested `if`s, checking first for `p`, then `q`, then looking for `h`. Without understanding your data I can't give you better advice.

Comment: What's `data[i]`? `data` is a dictionary, with string keys, it doesn't make sense to try to index it with integers. When the OP has posted malformed data, it's best to wait for them to fix it up before posting code that may not be valid.

Comment: Making an assumption that he forgot the `[]` in his post. i.e. `data = [{'x': 'y', 'a': 'b', 'p': {'l': ['m', 'n'], 'q': ['g']}}, {'another': 'dict'}]`

Comment: Sure, it _could_ be a list of dicts. But then it wouldn't raise `KeyError` when he tries to run your code.

Comment: It would if one of the dicts doesn't have `p` or `q`.